# ¿Cómo escribir texto con caracteres especiales en un documento RTF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, codificación, rtf

Estoy tratando de rellenar los campos de una plantilla en formato **.rtf** con los valores que obtengo de una base de datos. La plantilla (plantilla.rtf) esta formateada de la siguiente manera:

> Me llamo @nombre, y tengo @edad años.

Y en la función (escrita en c#) realizo lo siguiente:

```
protected void function(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Obtenemos los datos y los asignamos a variables

    Response.ContentType = "text/rtf";
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"documento.rtf\"");

    var f = new StringBuilder(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/ruta/plantilla.rtf")));

    f.Replace("@nombre", nombre); // nombre = "Óscar"
    f.Replace("@edad", edad); // edad = "20"

    Response.Write(f);
    Response.End();
}
```

Todo el proceso funciona correctamente, el problema lo tengo al insertar texto con caracteres especiales, como en el ejemplo que acabo de pasar (`nombre = "Óscar"`), ya que el documento resultante me queda de la siguiente manera:

> Me llamo Ã“scar, y tengo 20 años.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Has probado a pasarle la codificación a `ReadAllText` por ejemplo? `var f = new StringBuilder(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/ruta/plantilla.rtf"),Encoding.UTF8));`. Y ya de paso, `Response.Charset= "UTF-8"`

Comment: Había probado las dos cosas por separado y no funcionaban. Las acabo de probar juntas por sea caso y tampoco. Utilizando el formato `Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.ToString()` tampoco soluciona el problema.

Comment: Pues entonces, solo me queda una opción: que el archivo plantilla.rtf no esté codificado en UTF-8. Es posible que lo hayas creado con el bloc de notas? Por defecto almacena los archivos como `ANSI`. Abre el archivo con el bloc de notas, y dale a guardar como asegurandote de que en codificacion este seleccionado UTF-8.

Comment: En principio, la plantilla es algo que me envían y que no debería modificar. Sin embargo, abriéndolo en un editor de texto plano, su primera secuencia empieza por `{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1252...` por lo que confirmo que esta codificado en `ANSI`. Voy a probar a tratar de cambiarle la codificación.

Comment: Ok, lo imaginaba. Aunque en tu caso parece ser el archivo, añado una respuesta con las otras opciones por si en el futuro le sirven a alguien

Comment: Me las arreglé para modificar el archivo y codificarlo en `UTF-8` y pude comprobar que ya me reconoce bien los caracteres especiales. Aún así, lamentablemente yo no puedo modificar la plantilla que me pasan, por lo que busque otra solución. Doy por aceptada tu respuesta y añado la solución que estoy utilizando ahora mismo para los que no puedan cambiar la codificación ni modificar el fichero.

Comment: Si, si no puedes modificar la plantilla es una buena opción. Me alegro que al menos te diera una pista para poder resolverlo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes hacer tres cosas. Por un lado, al leer el archivo `rtf` asegurarte de que lo lees como `UTF-8`:

```
var f = new StringBuilder(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/ruta/plantilla.rtf"),Encoding.UTF8));
```

Por otro, asegurarte de lo mismo en el `Response`:

```
Response.Charset= "UTF-8"
```

Y por ultimo, hay que comprobar que el archivo `rtf` no esté ya codificado como `ANSI` en lugar de `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1):

Debido a la imposibilidad de modificar la codificación de la plantilla, opté por codificar los caracteres antes de escribirlos en la misma. De la siguiente manera:

```
f.Replace("@nombre", codificarString(nombre)); // nombre = "Óscar"
f.Replace("@edad", codificarString(edad)); // edad = "20"
```

Ahora envío cada **cadena de texto** a la función `codificarString` que esta a su vez envía cada **carácter** a la función `codificarChar`, devolviendo el carácter correspondiente codificado para que sea legible en `ANSI`:

```
public static string codificarChar(char c)
{
    int intCode = Convert.ToInt32(c);
    if (char.IsLetter(c) && intCode < 0x80)
    {
        return c.ToString();
    }
    return "\\u" + intCode + "?";   
}

public static string codificarString(string s)
{
    StringBuilder returned = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(char c in s)
    {
        returned.Append(codificarChar(c));
    }
    return returned.ToString();
}
```

De esta manera se escribe correctamente:

> Me llamo Óscar, y tengo 20 años.